# Where should I place the JDBC driver for tomcat pool under openshift using scalable apps?

Tags: tomcat, openshift, connection-pooling

I have a tomcat7 scalable app deployed at openshift, accessing postgres.

I followed the instructions at this blog 
https://www.openshift.com/blogs/jndi-tomcat-configuration-howto

Creating a lib folder under the $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR with the required jdbc driver, updating the catalina properties, and so on.

And it works for one gear very well, with connection pooling.

But performing some load tests, when a new gear starts, I started to get 404 errors. Investigating these errors, I discovered that the new gear was not finding the jdbc driver:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1445)
    ... 27 more
```

That happens because the way of openshift creating new gears: it copies only the app-deployments folder, but not the data dir. I managed to ssh to the gear, and the app-root/data folder was empty. No drivers, no working application.

So where should I place my jdbc drivers in order to the add-gear script copy it for each gear. Or there is another solution?

There is another detail: I always deploy my war files at the webapps folder. I wonder if there is some folder inside app-deployments that I could use to store my jar. I tried to copy the jar directly at app-deployments, but the result was a disaster.

I wonder if there is not a way to control the add-gear using action-hooks, but could not find out any example or reference to that kind of customization.

Comment: Perhaps the solution is to implement an action hook that copies the jar? but what hook!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action hook solved the problem!
First I created an action hook called "pre_start_jbossews" at the action_hooks folder, with the chmod to execute. The name MUST be in the **form pre_start_(cartrigde)**.
They are described here:
http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_user_guide.html#action-hooks

inside the hook I put this command:

```
wget -P $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/driver "http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/postgresql/postgresql/9.3-1100-jdbc41/postgresql-9.3-1100-jdbc41.jar"
```

and then I edited my catalina.properties, appending the driver folder **"${catalina.home}/../app-root/data/driver/*.jar"**

```
common.loader=${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/../app-root/data/driver/*.jar
```

It was not obvious, but every time a new gear is created, the start script of jbossews is ALSO executed at THAT GEAR. In fact, a gear boots as an individual machine, the entire OS is loaded.
So, if I could not copy the lib from the root gear, I still can wget it from maven. 
However, I think it would be more easier to have a common "data" folder copied to all gears at start (and only at start, to avoiding breaking gear isolation idea).

Answer (score 0):

The driver should always go to `CATALINA_HOME/lib`.

Comment: I can´t change the lib directory at openshift tomcat cartridge. It is a synlink. That´s why the author of the blog suggests to create another folder at the user data, and change the catalina.properties classloader. However, this folder is nor replicated when openshift scales.